# php copy file for each filename in array

Tags: php, copy

I am trying to move all the files in my array from one directory to another.

I have done some research and are using the php Copy() function.
here is my code so far:

```
$filenameArray = "img1.png,img2.png,img3.png";

$sourcePath = "/source/";
$savePath = "/newDir/";

$myArray = explode(',', $filenameArray);
$finalArray = print_r($myArray);

function copyFiles($finalArray,$sourcePath,$savePath) {
for($i = 0;$i < count($finalArray);$i++){
    copy($sourcePath.$finalArray[$i],$savePath.$finalArray[$i]);}
}
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

This is the unlink ive been attempting to use.

```
function copyFiles($finalArray,$sourcePath,$savePath) {
   foreach ($finalArray as $file){
     if (!copy($sourcePath.$file,$savePath.$file)) {
         echo "Failed to move image";
     }

     $delete[] = $sourcePath.$file;

   }

}

   // Delete all successfully-copied files
    foreach ( $delete as $file ) {
        unlink( $sourcePath.$file );
    }
```

**My Final Working Code**

the code below moves images in comma seperated array to new folder and removes them from current folder

```
$finalArray = explode(',', $filenameArray);

function copyFiles($finalArray,$sourcePath,$savePath) {
   foreach ($finalArray as $file){
     if (!copy($sourcePath.$file,$savePath.$file)) {
         echo "Failed to move image";
     }

   }

}

copyFiles( $finalArray, $sourcePath, $savePath);

function removeFiles($finalArray,$sourcePath) {
   foreach ($finalArray as $file){
     if (!unlink($sourcePath.$file)) {
         echo "Failed to remove image";
     }

   }

}

removeFiles( $finalArray, $sourcePath);
```

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing here ??

Comment: @pranavm.s the files arn't being moved

Comment: Does the web server have permission to write to newDir ?

Comment: @WilliamMacdonald yes, I used to move one file at a time with the copy() funtion using the same directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution :

```
$filenameArray = "img1.png,img2.png,img3.png";

$sourcePath = "/source/";
$savePath = "/newDir/";

$myArray = explode(',', $filenameArray);
$finalArray = $myArray;    //corrected this line

function copyFiles($finalArray, $sourcePath, $savePath) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($finalArray); $i++) 
    {
        copy($sourcePath.$finalArray[$i],$savePath.$finalArray[$i]);
    }
}
```

Hope you have right call to `function copyFiles()`.

**UPDATE for `unlink()` :**

Let me try to throw some light on your work (written code):

```
foreach ($finalArray as $file)
{
    if (!copy($sourcePath.$file,$savePath.$file)) 
    {
        echo "Failed to move image";
    }
    $delete[] = $sourcePath.$file;
}
```

**Contents of $delete :**

```
a. /source/img1.png
b. /source/img2.png
c. /source/img3.png
```

Now,

```
foreach ( $delete as $file ) 
{
    unlink( $sourcePath.$file );
}
```

**unlink() will be called with the following parameters:**

```
$sourcePath.$file : /source/./source/img1.png : /source//source/img1.png => No  such path exists
$sourcePath.$file : /source/./source/img2.png : /source//source/img2.png => No  such path exists
$sourcePath.$file : /source/./source/img3.png : /source//source/img3.png => No  such path exists
$sourcePath.$file : /source/./source/img4.png : /source//source/img4.png => No  such path exists
```

I think for this reason, unlink is not working.

The code to be written should be like the following:

```
foreach ( $delete as $file ) 
{
    unlink( $file );
}
```

**Now, unlink() will be called with the following parameters:**

```
a. /source/img1.png => path do exists
b. /source/img2.png => path do exists
c. /source/img3.png => path do exists
```

Do tell me if this does not solves the issue.

**Update as per Dave Lynch's code:**

```
$filenameArray = "img1.png,img2.png,img3.png";

$sourcePath = "/source/";
$savePath = "/newDir/";

$finalArray = explode(',', $filenameArray);

foreach ($finalArray as $file)
{
    $delete[] = $sourcePath.$file;
}

foreach ( $delete as $file ) 
{
     echo $sourcePath.$file . "</br>";
}
```

**Output:**

```
/source//source/img1.png
/source//source/img2.png
/source//source/img3.png
```

Please check.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: @Dave Lynch : Echo and see whether you are getting correct source and destination path

Comment: I got williams suggestion working but now i need a way of deleting successfully moved images from source/ ive tried using unlink() but no luck

Comment: @DaveLynch : Did you use `unlink()` like `unlink("source/" . $file)` ?

Comment: @DaveLynch : I have updated my answer and tried to solve the problem. See if it helps.

Comment: That hasn't worked either I'm afraid, ive create a second foreach loop with wrapped with a function to do the unlinking at that works :)

Comment: @DaveLynch: Did you read my explaination? Try to `echo` out the parameter you are passing in the `unlink()`.

Comment: @DaveLynch : I have added your code and showed the output. Please check

Comment: I've update my question with my working code. thanks for all your help i really appreciate it!

Comment: @Dave Lynch : You are most welcome. Upvote up or select it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not calling the copyFile function. Try this:

```
$filenameArray = "img1.png,img2.png,img3.png";

$sourcePath = "/source/";
$savePath = "/newDir/";

$finalArray = explode(',', $filenameArray);

function mvFiles($finalArray,$sourcePath,$savePath) {
   foreach ($finalArray as $file){
     if (!rename($sourcePath.$file,$savePath.$file)) {
         echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
     }
   }
}

mvFiles( $finalArray, $sourcePath, $savePath);
```

Comment: works! just need to remove the files from /source/ Thanks William!

Comment: You need to use rename function to move a file.